# How can I call a pointer of an QObject in a QML File?

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry, qml, blackberry-10

I'm developping an application for Blackberry 10 and I'm using the Momentics IDE (BB native SDK).

I get the following error when I try to execute the code below. Any one have an idea how can I fix this ?

**Error**

```
QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'DataHandler*' for property 'xxx::dataHandler'
asset:///main.qml:104: TypeError: Result of expression 'xxx.dataHandler' [undefined] is not an object.
Process 627863799 (xxx) terminated SIGSEGV code=1 fltno=11 ip=08055b30(/accounts/1000/appdata/com.ddd.xxx.testDev_e_xxx45b0f435/app/native/xxx@main+0x5d63) ref=006e0075
```

** **xxx.hpp** **

```
class xxx: public QObject {
Q_OBJECT

Q_PROPERTY(DataHandler* dataHandler READ getDataHandler)

public:
    xxx(bb::cascades::Application *app);
    virtual ~xxx() {
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE
    DataHandler* getDataHandler() const;

private:
    DataHandler* m_dataHandler;
}
```

** **xxx.cpp** **

```
xxx::xxx(bb::cascades::Application *app) :
        QObject(app) {
m_dataHandler = new DataHandler();
}
```

** **QML file** **

```
Button {
         id: backBtn
         objectName: "backBtnObject"
         text: qsTr("Back") + Retranslate.onLocaleOrLanguageChanged
         preferredWidth: backBtn.text.length
         visible: false
         onClicked: {
              xxx.dataHandler.displayLicencesList();
         }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register your pointer type like this

```
qRegisterMetaType<ClassA*>("ClassA*");
```

([source](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/14835-How-to-use-Q_DECLARE_METATYPE?p=76295#post76295))

Answer (score 2):

DataHandler is unknown type.

Q_PROPERTY docu says:

> The type can be any type supported by QVariant

I'd try to encapsulate your DataHandler* in QVariant and make the property of type QVariant.

You could create the value containing your DataHandler pointer e.g like this:

```
const int DATA_HANDLER = QVariant::UserType +1;
//...
QVariant dataHandler( DATA_HANDLER, myDataHandlerPointer );
```

Comment: Thx !! **DataHandler** is QObject class that I created for loading data stuffs. I don't know why it doesn't work? If you check this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html), you will see that's possible to call pointer in the Q_Property.

Comment: @user2072762: OK, interesting. This docu  [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html#registering-c-types-with-the-qml-type-system) says, QObject-derived classes may be used as types if they were registered. Have you seen the chapter **Registering C++ types with the QML type system**? Maybe qmlRegisterType() could help?