# Registering Qt::[Enum/Flag] as QtMetaType

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I wanted to create a object to access the values of a [`QMouseEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html).

This event has e.g.

```
Qt::MouseButton QMouseEvent::button() const
```

So I add to my class `MyQMLMouseEvent`

```
Q_PROPERTY(Qt::MouseButton button READ button)
```

and the necessary getter.

I expected, on the QML side, I can use it as such:

```
myQmlMouseEvent.button === Qt.ButtonLeft
```

as `Qt.ButtonLeft` is available, and used e.g. with the `MouseArea`'s `clicked` signal.

Now for a test, I handle the signal in which I pass this `MyQMLMouseEvent`-instance in QML like this:

```
onMyQMLMousEvent: console.log(JSON.stringify(myMouseEvent))
```

which prints most properties, but fails on the `Qt::MouseButton` type. For this it gives me the error:

> QMetaProperty::read: *Unable to handle unregistered datatype `'Qt::MouseButton'` for property `'MyQMLMouseEvent::button'`*

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478866/2056452) they say I might solve this by calling `qRegisterMetaType` to register those type.
I am unsure if in this case this is right or would even work for

- `Qt` is already available in QML - so registering parts of it again seems wrong to me?
- Can I `qRegisterMetaType` enums and flags from some class I have little control about?

---

Intrestingly: What fails is `Qt::MouseButton` and `Qt::MouseEventFlags` but not so `Qt:MouseButtons` (which is only an alias to `Qt::MouseButton`).
This means I could circumvent the problem with `Qt::MouseButton` by just changing the type to the plural, and the `Qt::MouseEventFlags` could be passed as `int` as it is indeed not available in QML (should be `Qt.MouseEventCreatedDoubleClick`)

**Still, just out of curiosity, and if it might get necessary in future:** *What is the right way to register enums and flags from the `Qt` namespace if they are not registered yet?
I don't really want to register them every time in my `main.cpp` whenever I use some completly different class.*

Comment: @Velkan I did not mean for you to delete your answer, as I do believe it contained useful info regarding exposing enums from namespaces outside a class, only it does not seem to work for the Qt namespace which is linked from a shared library. If you choose to edit the answer, I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the `Q_PROPERTY` type as `int`

There is no need to declare or register any extra metatypes just to use an enum.

### C++

```
class MouseButtonObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int button READ button)

public:
    explicit MouseButtonObject(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    Qt::MouseButton button() { return Qt::LeftButton; }
};
```

### QML

```
if (mouseButtonObject.button === Qt.LeftButton) {
    console.log("button is Left Button")
}
```