# Filter model items in tree view

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

I have a model class:

```cpp
class ItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum ItemRoles {
        ItemRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        NameRole,
        IdRole,
        FilterRole // To be used in filtering
    };

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

}
```

Model returns data according to roles:

```
QVariant ItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    Item *item = itemFromIndex(index);

    switch (role) {
    case ItemRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(item);
    case NameRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(item->entity()->objectName());
    case IdRole:
        return QVariant::fromValue(item->entity()->id().id());
    case FilterRole:
    {
        switch (item->itemTask()) {
        case Item::ItemTask::ToBeFiltered:
            return QVariant::fromValue(QString("yes"));
        default:
            return QVariant::fromValue(QString("no"));
        }
    }
    default:
        return QVariant();
    }

}
```

I have used a `QSortFilterProxyModel` member for parent class to filter my model:

```cpp
class ParentClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ItemModel             * sceneModel      READ sceneModel      CONSTANT)
    Q_PROPERTY(QSortFilterProxyModel * sceneModelProxy READ sceneModelProxy CONSTANT)

private:
    ItemModel             *m_sceneModel;
    QSortFilterProxyModel *m_sceneModelProxy;

}
```

`QSortFilterProxyModel` is set up at parent class constructor:

```cpp
ParentClass::ParentClass(QObject *parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , m_sceneModel(new ItemModel(this))
    , m_sceneModelProxy(new QSortFilterProxyModel())
{
    // Proxy to filter out unwanted items from tree-view of model
    // Looks into a specific role for each item,
    // if data value returned for that role passes the regexp, then include item in proxy model
    m_sceneModelProxy->setFilterRole(ItemModel::ItemRoles::FilterRole);
    m_sceneModelProxy->setFilterRegExp("^no$");
    m_sceneModelProxy->setSourceModel(m_sceneModel);
}
```

Parent class is registered as a QML type and is used on QML:

```
ParentClass {
    id: parentClass
}
```

Now on QML, I'm using `TreeView` type to show the model:

```
TreeView {
    model: parentClass.sceneModel
    selection: ItemSelectionModel {
        model: parentClass.sceneModel
    }
    style: TreeViewStyle { // ... }
    itemDelegate: FocusScope { // ... }
    TableViewColumn { role: "name" }
}
```

There is **quite some** logic inside `TreeView` which depends on `parentClass.sceneModel`. I replaced all `parentClass.sceneModel` instances with `parentClass.sceneModelProxy`.

The original tree view without any proxy works fine:

[image: No proxy]

After applying proxy, tree view is empty:

[image: With proxy]

I have spent some time to debug the `QSortFilterProxyModel` usage. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: Is the parent element passing the filter? See also `recursiveFilteringEnabled` of QSFPM.

Comment: In general: strings and regexps for filtering elements? ERK! Use a boolean property and filterAcceptsRow or similar...

Comment: @peppe Thanks! I tried `setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(true)`, but the problem remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at Qt Creator logs while running the application, I accidentally noticed this log:

> QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'QSortFilterProxyModel*' for property 'ParentClass_QML_193::sceneModelProxy'

I resolved the above log by [a suggested approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25478866/3405291) of registering `QSortFilterProxyModel*` pointer:

```cpp
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

qRegisterMetaType<QSortFilterProxyModel*>("QSortFilterProxyModel*");
```

Now QML `TreeView` filters out unwanted items correctly =)

Comment: or just include the `QSortFilterProxyModel` in your header -where you declared the property- instead of using forward declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Try either setting `m_sceneModelProxy->setDynamicSortFilter(true)` or call `m_sceneModelProxy->invalidate()` once after setup.

Comment: I set it to `true`, but the problem remains. Looks like [dynamicSortFilter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#dynamicSortFilter-prop) property is set to `true` by default.

Comment: Also `m_sceneModelProxy->invalidate();` didn't resolve the issue =(

Comment: Then I assume something is wrong with your model, maybe you should provide a  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Does item->itemTask() return a valid value that is handled in the switch() statement? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Thanks =) I'm going to provide a minimal example. It might take some time since the model is a big one.

Comment: Another thing: setFilterRegExp() keeps the items that match the expression. Do the items you expect to see return "no" for FilterRole?

Comment: Right! I know it sounds counter intuitive, but `no` means they are *not* filtered!

Comment: Good point! Stepping through the code in debug mode, shows `item->itemTask()` returns a valid value. It is handled correctly inside `switch ()` and `"no"` is returned for items which should *not* be filtered.