# Filter model in tree view

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

This is a follow up question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60507762/3405291) which is already fixed.

---

My model has some custom functions which are being called inside my tree view. For example, I have two custom functions in my `ItemModel` class:

```cpp
class ItemModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    // ...

    Q_INVOKABLE void addExpandedItem(const QModelIndex &index);
    Q_INVOKABLE void removeExpandedItem(const QModelIndex &index);
}
```

Using `ItemModel` class as `sceneModel` property in a `ParentClass`:

```cpp
class ParentClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ItemModel * sceneModel READ sceneModel CONSTANT)

private:
    ItemModel *m_sceneModel;

}
```

In my QML tree view, I'm **calling** / **invoking** those custom functions like:

```
TreeView {
    model: parentClass.sceneModel
    selection: ItemSelectionModel {
        model: parentClass.sceneModel
    }

    onExpanded: {
        model.addExpandedItem(index) // Calling custom function
    }
    onCollapsed: {
        model.removeExpandedItem(index) // Calling custom function
    }
}
```

---

Now, when I intend to filter my model by `QSortFilterProxyModel` just as described in [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60507762/3405291), I'm having trouble calling those custom functions through `QSortFilterProxyModel` proxy model. I'm receiving such errors:

```
qrc:/.../...Tree.qml:191: TypeError: Property 'addExpandedItem' of object QSortFilterProxyModel(0x1f197c082c0) is not a function
```

Therefore, I wonder how I might be able to call custom functions of my model through `QSortFilterProxyModel` proxy model.

Comment: I'd suggest doing all your QML side filtering via. this very handy library https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel . That way you can call the addExpandedItem/removeExpandedItem on the original model ad the SortFilterProxyModel will transparently get updated with those new items.

Alternatively you can expose a property like `sortedFilteredModel` as a Q_PROPERTY of the original model and expose your original model to QML, but use `model: originalModel.sortedFilteredModel` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `QVariant` in `Q_PROPERTY` of your parent class. Getter function should return your class instance like this:

```
return QVariant::fromValue(m_sceneModel);
```

It works when I do it like this. Also, are you sure that `TreeView` passes `QModelIndex` to your method? To my knowledge it passes just `int` while real model index can be accessed only by C++ `data` function.