# How to bind QVector<AClass*>* in ListView?

Tags: c++, qt, listview, qml

I've tried with `QVector<AClass*>` instead of `QVector<AClass*>*` and it works with the following in `qml`:

```
ListView{
    model: testContext.list
    delegate: Text{
        text: modelData.name + " " + modelData.age
    }
}
```

When I added one more `*` to make it `QVector<AClass*>*` I got this error:

> QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype
>   'QVector*' for property 'Test::list'

to fix it according to solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329413/how-can-i-call-a-pointer-of-an-qobject-in-a-qml-file), I've added `qRegisterMetaType<QVector<AClass*>*>("QVector<AClass*>*");` in `constructor` like this:

```
Test::Test(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    qRegisterMetaType<QVector<AClass*>*>("QVector<AClass*>*");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testContext", this);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
}
```

above `constructor` is in `.cpp` file of the following class:

```
class Test : public QObject
{  
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QVector<AClass*> *vector;

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVector<AClass*>* list READ list WRITE setList NOTIFY listChanged)

public:
    explicit Test(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QVector<AClass*>* list() {return vector;}
    void setList(QVector<AClass*>* value){vector = value; emit listChanged();}
    Q_SIGNAL void listChanged();
    Q_INVOKABLE void addItem();
    Q_INVOKABLE void removeItem(int index);
};
```

in my `main.cpp` I've these:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test test;
    return app.exec();
}
```

`QVector` has items in it BUT nothing shows up in `ListView`! Here is `AClass`:

```
class AClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(int age READ age WRITE setAge NOTIFY ageChanged)

public:
    explicit AClass(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QString name() const {return mName;}
    void setName(QString value) {mName = value; emit nameChanged();}
    int age() const {return mAge;}
    void setAge(int value){mAge = value; emit ageChanged();}
    Q_SIGNAL void nameChanged();
    Q_SIGNAL void ageChanged();

private:
    QString mName;
    int mAge;
};
```

If I use `QVector<AClass*>` or `QVector<AClass>` instead of `QVector<AClass*>*` I see items in `ListView`.

Comment: The big question is: Why do you want to use `QVector<AClass*>*`?

Comment: @eyllanesc, why not? It just came to my mind while reading a document and testing.

Comment: QML can only recognize some basic data types such as QObjects *, int, floats, QUrl, QString, etc. and the Qt containers(QVector, QList, etc) of those basic types **but cannot recognize a pointer of a container**.